# Open category filters by default in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, filtered-nav

Is it possible to open category filters in the left pane by default in Magento 2 Luma theme.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just copy

```
vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\Magento_LayeredNavigation\templates\layer\view.phtml
```

into

```
app\design\frontend\<your_company>\<your_theme>\Magento_LayeredNavigation\templates\layer\
```

and change the 'data-mage-init' attribute as follow:

```
<?php foreach ($block->getFilters() as $filter): ?>
    <?php if ($filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
        <?php if (!$wrapOptions): ?>
            <?php $collapsibleRange = implode(' ', range(0, $filter->getItemsCount())); ?>
            <strong role="heading" aria-level="2" class="block-subtitle filter-subtitle"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Shopping Options') ?></strong>
            <div class="filter-options" id="narrow-by-list" data-role="content" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": "<?= $collapsibleRange ?>", "multipleCollapsible": true}}'>
        <?php  $wrapOptions = true; endif; ?>
        <div data-role="collapsible" class="filter-options-item">
        <div data-role="title" class="filter-options-title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __($filter->getName()) ?></div>
        <div data-role="content" class="filter-options-content"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->render($filter); ?></div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Can this be done using custom module?

Comment: can you update full code of view.phtml

Comment: <?php endforeach; ?>

Only Need to add foreach close and working perfect !

Comment: what need to add in code  if we need to open it by default particularly for some filters only?

Comment: This opens the filters, however the close carret doesn't activate any more. The filters cannot close. Any solutions for this?

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  Also just in case someone else tries this, I had to flush the cache in order to see the change.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test it but I think if you change `line 12` to `true` it should work.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/077584c99ebb8007cad176c3b9a0144a05c259cd/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/lib/collapsible.js#L12

I don't know what the proper way to override js files in Magento 2 is yet. So you should look that up to do it the Magento way.

Comment: I've changed a number of collapsible.js files to try and get this working but it doesn't work yet. It looks like the right direction to be looking though.

Comment: If you initialise the collapsible without passing the "opened" argument you're right. But if the argument is passed it will be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

I acidentally found working code:

```
<div class="filter-options" id="narrow-by-list" data-role="content" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": "0, 1, 2, 3, 4", "multipleCollapsible": false}}'>
```

I don't know if this is proper solution, but all filters are open and collapsing working. Also mobile open filter button works.