# How to make all the filters active in layered navigation?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

By default in `Luma` theme all the filters come in `closed state` and to **make active all the filters** in `layered navigation` I have tried this solution [Open category filters by default in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102259/open-category-filters-by-default-in-magento-2) and hopefully got succeed in same.

But Now I see some strange behavior, **Like few of filters are** `active` by default and **few are in** `closed state`. On **different categories** it behave **differently**.

anyone with same problem kindly tell the solution if have any

Comment: Please try with https://www.magevision.com/blog/post/open-category-filters-by-default-magento-2/

Comment: thanks but it has some strange issue , few are closed and few are active

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem solved by placing altering some code lines and running few commands

In `/app/design/frontend/packagename/themename/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml`

1 ) Added the following line inside the foreach loop (foreach ($block->getFilters() as $filter) ):

```
<?php $range = implode(' ', range(0, $filter->getItemsCount())); ?>
```

2. modify the div with class filter-options inside this loop, change active to as per below:

   div class="filter-options" id="narrow-by-list" data-role="content" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": "", "multipleCollapsible": true}}'>

reference: https://www.magevision.com/blog/post/open-category-filters-by-default-magento-2/

After all this I run few commands may be it was not working because cache enable or some other problem but after running these commands , it worked great

```
php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```